# C: MSVC2008 Malloc and crashing program

Tags: c, malloc

This question might be remedial but I am having a lot of trouble with malloc. Why does my progrm crash upon freeing memory?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *arr[10];
    void *mem = malloc( 10 * sizeof(int) );
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=9;i++) {
        arr[i] = (int*) mem + i*sizeof(int);
        *arr[i]= 9-i;
    }
    //void** ar = (void**) arr;
    //medianSort(ar, cmp, 0, 9);
    free(mem); //crashes here
    return 0;
}
```

**Runtime Error Message Box Reports**:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in
>   medianSort.exe. This may be due to a
>   corruption of the heap, which
>   indicates a bug in medianSort.exe or
>   any of the DLLs it has loaded. This
>   may also be due to the user pressing
>   F12 while medianSort.exe has focus.
>   The output window may have more
>   diagnostic information.

**The following is is the error block from malloc.c**:

```
#ifdef _WIN64
    return HeapAlloc(_crtheap, 0, size ? size : 1);
#else  /* _WIN64 */
    if (__active_heap == __SYSTEM_HEAP) {
        return HeapAlloc(_crtheap, 0, size ? size : 1); //crashes here
    } else
    if ( __active_heap == __V6_HEAP ) {
        if (pvReturn = V6_HeapAlloc(size)) {
            return pvReturn;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing beyond allocated memory. Note that `(int*) mem` is `int` pointer, so adding 1 actually moves memory location by `sizeof(int)` bytes. In other words, you shouldn't be doing `sizeof(int)` yourself within loop, because pointer arithmetic says compiler does that for you.

Comment: would be better if you'd declare `int *mem` from the start and just use it naturally such as `arr[i] = mem + i;`